# Can the keyboard shortcut to turn on/off Filter Keys in Microsoft Windows 7 be changed?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, filterkeys

Can the keyboard shortcut to turn on/off [FilterKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FilterKeys) in Microsoft Windows 7 be changed?

By default, one needs to press the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> for 8 seconds:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some looking, both in my Windows 7 machine (VM) and my Windows 10 machine (Host).

There does not appear to be any way to change this assignment. The operating system must select a little used sequence of 3 presses and the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key does this. The OS must have tailored code to do this.

I do not see any way to make another key take its spot.

Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> has been the selected key for a number of operating systems. Windows 7, 8 and 10.